# what are the options to implement random search?

Tags: python, ray

So i want to implement random search but there is no clear cut example as to how to do this. I am confused between the following methods:

1. tune.randint()
2. ray.tune.suggest.BasicVariantGenerator()
3. tune.sample_from(lambda spec: blah blah np.random.choice())

Can someone please explain how and why these methods are same/different for implementing random search.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you don't need to use `ray.tune.suggest.BasicVariantGenerator()`.

For the other two choices, it's up to what suits your need. `tune.randint()` is just a thin wrapper around `tune.sample_from(lambda spec: np.random.randint(...))`. You can do more expressive/conditional searches with the latter, but the former is easier to use.